# Apache Axis2 User's Guide - Creating Clients

Tags: apache, apache-axis

I am following along in the "Apache Axis2 User's Guide - Creating Clients"

http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients.html#choosingclient

My problem is when I execute the command line argument from the guide:

%AXIS2_HOME%\bin\WSDL2Java -uri Axis2UserGuide.wsdl -p org.apache.axis2.axis2userguide -d adb -s

I get the following response, I am also unsure where axis2userguide.wsdl resides in the axis2 distribution.

Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: Unable to resolve imported document at 'Axis2UserGuide.wsdl'.: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file was not found: file:/C:/Desktop/axis2-1.6.2/bin/Axis2UserGuide.wsdl

Is axis2userguide.wsdl a file included in the distro, or is it an arbitrary file name?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to the complete the step of creating the stub in the tutorial by doing the following:

C:\axis2-1.6.2\samples\quickstart>set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\axis2-1.6.2\samples\quickstart\build\classes;

C:\axis2-1.6.2\samples\quickstart>%AXIS2_HOME%\bin\java2wsdl -cp . -cn samples.quickstart.service.pojo.StockQuoteService -of StockQuoteService.wsdl

C:\axis2-1.6.2\samples\quickstart>%AXIS2_HOME%\bin\WSDL2Java -uri StockQuoteService.wsdl -p org.apache.axis2.StockQuoteService.wsdl -d adb -s

The root cause was the file didn't exist, and my CLASSPATH wasn't set.

Hope this helps someone else.